# Как переключить внешний вид карточек товаров?

Tags: php, html, jquery, css, битрикс

Как реализовать изменение внешнего вида карточек товаров?
Наверное, нужно будет через jquery добавлять необходимый класс, который будет менять внешний вид? просьба соориентировать в каком направлении двигаться

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А в чем собсна говоря проблема? Как уже отмечалось: вы уже сами все сказали.

Если Вас нужно подтолкнуть, то вот толчок на **Bootstrap**:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Optional CSS -->
  <style>
    .css-block {
      border: 1px double black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Selector -->
  <div class="gridSelector">Переключаем (клик)</div>

  <!-- Content -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="css-block col-12">1</div>
      <div class="css-block col-12">2</div>
      <div class="css-block col-12">3</div>
      <div class="css-block col-12">4</div>
      <div class="css-block col-12">5</div>
      <div class="css-block col-12">6</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".gridSelector").click(function() {
        if ($('.css-block').hasClass('col-4')) {
          $('.css-block').addClass('col-12');
          $('.css-block').removeClass('col-4');
        } else {
          $('.css-block').addClass('col-4');
          $('.css-block').removeClass('col-12');
        }
        return false;
      });
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```